# How close to electronics can a relay be?

Tags: relay, electromagnetism

For example [this](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/670/pr24-3044675.pdf) relay - how close can it be to microcontroller, like PIC?

What if I have few relays - can I put them next to each other?

What if they carry high AC (~40A) current - would that also affect the electronics?

Comment: If you're concerned about magnetic issues, you can get magnetic shielding to contain the magnetic field closer to the relay. This is more of a concern for relays adjacent to other relays or magnetically-sensitive components, though; most things don't care about (static, reasonable-strength (where reasonable means "not as strong as an MRI machine")) magnetic fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of things to consider here.

> What if I have few relays - can I put them next to each other?

*How much will one relay increase in temperature during operation?*  The datasheet reports 0.9W, which would be fine in air.  But if several of these were placed all next to each other (each emitting 0.9W of heat) in a tight enclosure with no airflow or potted, this could cause significant temperature rise. How high, depends on many factors.  It can be calculated/estimated with a bit of work; search here for [calculate temperature rise](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=calculate+temperature+rise).

*Being 0.9W each, driver(s) will have to be used.*  Most PICs can only output 25mA max, so a BJT or MOSFET (or array) will be needed to switch them.  These also need "freewheeling" diodes to prevent an inductive spike from the coil at turn-off from destroying the BJTs/MOSFETs.

> how close can [a relay] be to microcontroller, like PIC?

*PICs are largely immune to magnetism.*  So a relay could be physically close to the PIC, provided no other limits are exceeded such as temperature.  Any chip *will* misbehave if a strong enough magnetic field is present, but that requires a *very strong* field.

> What if they carry high AC (~40A) current - would that also affect the electronics?

*The relay contact current can affect the surrounding circuitry.*  How important this is depends on what is being switched:

- If purely resistive (such as a heater) it should not be a problem.
- If an AC inductive (motor) or capacitive (power supply) load, this can create significant voltage/current spikes.  If anticipating such spikes (only at turn-on and turn-off), make the current-carrying traces wider for lower resistance.  If these turn on and off frequently, consider the following.
- If anticipating frequent/continuous switching noise, route those high-current traces far away from the microcontroller and add an AC "snubber" across the relay contacts to absorb that energy.  How far to take this protection (to make robust devices which work well for consumers by not emitting radiation and being largely immune to it) is a whole separate field of electronics.  Research "EMC compliance" for more info.

Comment: There might be a problem if the relay drivers share a common power supply with the PIC. You should consider the liberal use of decoupling capacitors both close to the relays and to the PIC.

Comment: Yes, I would pot them inside silicone.

Comment: Coil power is not the only contributor to power dissipation. With 40A continuous through the internal busbars and the contacts you could easily dissipate 5W inside the relay. This is very hard to calculate due to the way the voltage drop of the contact material varies with current and temperature. If you're planning to have several relays adjacent, each with 40A, then you should build a prototype first to check the Trise.

Comment: All valid points.  The potting compound acts as a thermal insulator, trapping heat.  Have seen plenty of potted devices fail due to heat, which then cannot be repaired or even recycled.